# Symlinking `init.el` in

Tags: emacs, dot-files

I would like to symlink my emacs `init.el` into a dotfiles repo - located at `~/Documents/Dotfiles`. However, when I attempt to do so the command fails even though my prompt doesn't return an error - `ls -la` doesn't show a link there. For example, I might do the following:

`ln -s ~/.emacs.d/init.el ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/init.el`

Are emacs configs - due to their being, "under the covers", a directory - different in some way than other files you might want to symlink?

[image: .emacs.d]

**Tl;dr** Aliases are weird and although the commands work, this link doesn't show in `ls -la` which is not really emacs' fault.

[image: symlink]

Comment: Clarify "the command fails".

Comment: Trying this again, I get a "File exists" response - might be going in the wrong direction. See the screenshot above.

Comment: What shows `ls -la /Users/Chris/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/init.el`? If present delete the file and execute the command in verbose mode: `ln -sv ...`

Comment: It looks like you have created the file `~/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/init.el`already. In that case `ln` will fail because the file already exists. Remove the file `~/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/init.el` and then create the symlink.

Comment: @mmmint `ln: /Users/Chris/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/init.el: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, in my case this happens when the target link has directories which doesnt exist.
Try this:

File should exist:

```
file /Users/Chris/.emacs.d/init.el
```

Remove previous symbolic link if present:

```
rm /Users/Chris/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/init.el
```

Now create needed directories:

```
mkdir -p /Users/Chris/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/
```

And create symolic link:

```
ln -s /Users/Chris/.emacs.d/init.el /Users/Chris/Documents/Dotfiles/.emacs.d/init.el
```